# java.lang.IllegalStateException: no current navigation node in Kotlin NavigationComponent App

Tags: firebase, kotlin, navigation-drawer

I was developing an Kotin App which make use of Navigation component to moves between the diferents screen of the App.

My problems comes when I try to separate the root_navigation.xml of the main_navigation.xml

The main structure of my app is a splashScreen which send you to LoginScreen, where you can authenticated which firebase via Googe Provider or email/password provider.

The HGoogle Authentication works fine, and send you to the HomeFragment of the App, but the Authentication with email/password rise the above title error.

The code of my navigation files are the following

mobile_navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_login">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_login"
        android:name="com.example.appadoskotlin2.ui.login.LoginFragment"
        android:label="Login"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/navigation_login_to_navigation_home"
            app:destination="@id/nav_home"/>
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="com.example.appadoskotlin2.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/navigation_home_to_navigation_item_home"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_item_home"/>
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_home"
        android:name="com.example.appadoskotlin2.ui.home.ItemServiceFragment"
        android:label="Servicios"
        tools:layout="@layout/item_list">
        <argument
            android:name="item"
            app:argType="com.example.appadoskotlin2.data.Service"/>

    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_contract"
        android:name="com.example.appadoskotlin2.ui.contract.ContractFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_contract"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_contract">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/navigation_contract_to_navigation_item_contract"
        app:destination="@id/navigation_item_contract"/>
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_contract"
        android:name="com.example.appadoskotlin2.ui.home.ItemServiceFragment"
        android:label="Servicios"
        tools:layout="@layout/item_list">
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_publish"
        android:name="com.example.appadoskotlin2.ui.publish.PublishFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_publish"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_publish">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/navigation_publish_to_navigation_item_publish"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_item_publish"/>
    </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_item_publish"
            android:name="com.example.appadoskotlin2.ui.publish.ItemPublishFragment"
            android:label="Servicios"
            tools:layout="@layout/item_list">
        </fragment>

</navigation>
```

root_navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_splash">

    <activity
        android:id="@+id/navigation_splash"
        android:name="com.example.appadoskotlin2.SplashActivity"
        android:label="activity_splash"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_splash" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_splash_to_navigation_login"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_login" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:id="@+id/navigation_login"
        android:name="com.example.appadoskotlin2.MainActivity"
        android:label="activity_login"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_main" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_login_to_navigation_main"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_main" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:id="@+id/navigation_main"
        android:name="com.example.appadoskotlin2.MainActivity"
        android:label="MainActivity"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_main"/>

</navigation>
```

And the code of my LoginFragment and MainActivty of the App are these:

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.appadoskotlin2

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.appadoskotlin2.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.example.appadoskotlin2.ui.home.HomeFragment

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar)

        binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }

        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
        val navView: NavigationView = binding.navView
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.nav_login,
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_contract, R.id.nav_publish), drawerLayout)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

LoginFragment.kt

```
package com.example.appadoskotlin2.ui.login

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import com.example.appadoskotlin2.R
import com.example.appadoskotlin2.databinding.FragmentLoginBinding
import com.example.appadoskotlin2.ui.diologs.LoginDialog
import com.example.appadoskotlin2.ui.diologs.RegisterDialog
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions
import com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth

class LoginFragment: Fragment() {
    private val RC_SIGN_IN = 123

    private lateinit var navController : NavController
    private var _binding: FragmentLoginBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null
    private var mGoogleSignIn: GoogleSignInClient? = null
    private var btn_google: MaterialButton? = null
    private var btn_register: MaterialButton? = null
    private var btn_login: MaterialButton? = null
    private var diolog_register: RegisterDialog? = null
    private var diolog_login: LoginDialog? = null

    //TODO("Configurar firebase y linkear la vista")

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentLoginBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        initView(root)

        initListeners()

        return root
    }

    private fun initListeners() {
        val loginActivity: LoginFragment = this
        btn_google?.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            createRequest()
            signIn()
        })
        btn_register?.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            diolog_register = RegisterDialog(firebaseAuth, loginActivity)
            fragmentManager?.let { it1 -> diolog_register!!.show(it1, "RegisterDiolog") }
        })
        btn_login?.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            diolog_login = LoginDialog(firebaseAuth, this.context)
            fragmentManager?.let { it1 -> diolog_login!!.show(it1, "LoginDiolog") }
        })

    }

    fun initView(root: View){
        btn_google = root.findViewById(R.id.btn_google)
        btn_register = root.findViewById(R.id.btn_register)
        btn_login = root.findViewById(R.id.btn_login)
        context?.let { FirebaseApp.initializeApp(it) }
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    }
    private fun signIn() {
        val signInIntent = mGoogleSignIn!!.signInIntent
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
        showHome()
    }

    private fun showHome() {
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this.requireView())
        navController.navigate(R.id.navigation_login_to_navigation_home)
        Toast.makeText(context, "Login completed successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    private fun createRequest() {
        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken("786240463795-o92gljk39cmdd0pra162arebskntkdu5.apps.googleusercontent.com")
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
        mGoogleSignIn = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this.activity, gso)
    }
    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

As I say everythings works fine until I try to separate the navigation in those two files, in order to differentiate between the LoginNavigation, and the Naviation inside the App once the user is logged.

I don't know if the fact of the LoginScreen be a fragment have something related which the problem.

I hope you can help, and  if it's like this take thanks in advance !

[EDIT]

Added the navigation.xml as I changed it after several tips:

Still through the same error.

mobile_navigation.xml

[image]

root_navigation.xml

[image]

Comment: Did you added  Navigation Component dependencies ??  In App build.gradle

Comment: Of course the dependecy is added

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you implement the navigation graph right way. use fragments.

```
root_navigation.xml
```

[image]

```
mobile_navigation.xml
```

[image]

add here your desired fragments you want to navigate from login.

(I suggest use login fragment in splash screen for your app launch. and other fragments implement through main activity)

Comment: I implement the changes, and still through the same error.

Comment: Can you add Navigation graph screen shot in question?

Comment: I've just already added !

Comment: Ok I will update my answer.

Comment: Oke I see your point, but in my case my Login is an Activity, as my splashScreen. So the structure is quite diferent, isn't it? As I see in root_navigation.xml should implement the activities naviation to the navigation_main, which contain the fragments navigation

Comment: What is navigation_main it's fragment or activity?

Comment: navigation_main is the navigation between the fragments which made the App itself, the root_navigation is the login part of the App. Or at least is like as I though at the beggining

Comment: Ok, so you can implement your splash_screen and login_screen in navigation_main and after login you navigate to your mobile_navigation. Where you want to change the navigation root. Make sure you clear back stack after login.